# Removing single quotes from comparison in select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table where a field can have single quotes, but I need to be able to search by that field without single quotes. For example, if the search query is "Johns favorite", I need to be able to find a row where that field contains "John's favorite". I was looking into regex for it, but that seems to return a 0 or 1 when used in a select statement, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
SELECT 
   IF( 
       REPLACE("John's favorite","'","") = "Johns favorite" , 
       "found",
       "not found"
   )
```

It's *not optimal* but it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

This will give you the distance between two strings. I.e. you can check whether levensthein distance is less than 3, which means, less than 3 operations are required to be equal.

Comment: i think its a overkill for this scenario but +1 for a very useful function, i needed something like this in numerous occasions :d